# Flex Tweening leads to high CPU usage

Tags: apache-flex, cpu-usage, flex4.5, gsap

I'm using TweenLite from greensock in a flex game. I have the requirement to perform some long animations where one object needs to go from x1 to x2 within hours. this is what im doing:

```
TweenLite.fromTo(obj, duration, {x:x1}, {x:x2});
```

When the animation starts immediately the cpu usage goes over 20% and remain this way untill the animation is over. since the animation could take a lot of time to complete i need something that doesnt affect the cpu usage so drastically.

any idea?

Comment: Could you provide an example so we can see this high CPU usage spike for ourselves to better help you? You could also try adding `immediateRender:false` to your `fromTo()` tween. from tweens render immediately by default. So try setting `immediateRender:false` and see if that helps.. if not please provide a codepen or jsfiddle code example so we see this high CPU in context. You could have other things affecting the CPU. Also make sure you are using the latest version of TweenLite or TweenMax. Thanks! GreenSock fromTo() Docs: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/fromTo/

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i'll try your suggestion and write back when i have the results. it would be amazing to solve this one.

Comment: Also you could use the GSAP set() method to set your initial CSS values and then use a to() tween to animate to your new values overtime. See GSAP set() method: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/set/

Comment: Thanks for another suggestion, really appreciate it, i will soon try to use all this and post the result. using immediateRender:false seems to reduce the usage, but i want to make the fix properly before making any conclusions.

Comment: You can also add `TweenLite.lagSmoothing(0);` if you need to reduce high CPU usage. Please see this: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/static_lagSmoothing/ .. `lagSmoothing()` Permits you to control what happens when too much time elapses between two ticks (updates) of the engine, adjusting the core timing mechanism to compensate and avoid "jumps".